# Replace groupByKey code with reduceByKey

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following code:

```
dataframe.coalesce(64).rdd.map(lambda row: (row.id, row))\
 .groupByKey().foreach(write_to_redis)
```

Can someone please suggest a better way of writing in using aggregateByKey or reduceByKey?

Any general solution to make this more efficient is also welcome.

Comment: why do you want to use aggregateByKey and reduceByKey? why not use the dataset API with map partitions?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: What does `write_to_redis` take as an input?

Comment: The row of the rdd. Isn't foreach suppose to do that automatically? as in def write_to_redis(row): # Do Stuff